# Find the other end of a curve after a cut in an image

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing

I would like to follow a curve (with matlab or opencv) and to find the other end of it when it is cut by an empty space like this example, which is simplified to illustrate the problem:
[Link to image of cut curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEnoD.png)

Real images are more like this one: [Link to real image to analyse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLPrR.png)

To follow the curve, I can use a skeleton and look at the neighbourhood. The problem is that I don't know how to find the other end efficiently.

I don't think that closing or opening operations could help because as shown on the previous image, there are other curves and the two parts of the curve are quite far from each other so it could lead to boundaries between the different curves instead of the two parts.

I was thinking about polynomial evaluation which could be a solution for simple curves but I am not sure about the precision I could get. If I use a skeleton, I have to find exactly the right pixel or to search in a reasonable neighbourhood which would take some time and once again, as there are other curves in the images, I have to be sure that I will find the good one.

That's why I am searching for an existing function which could estimate precisely the trajectory of the curve and give an usefull output to go further and find the second part of the curve.

If that kind of function doesn't exist, I'm open to any other way of analysing the problem if it can help.

Comment: If all your curves admit an "easy" parametrization you might want to try the [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform).

Comment: I'm going to read this and I'll come back if needed. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I will start to explain with the first image you provided, you can implement common OpenCV function useful for detecting contour(black region in your case as you have binary image) known as **cv2.findContours()**, which returns the coordinates of the edges of the surface detected then you can plot each detected contour separately in a blank image to get the edge of your desired line.

Now coming to your 2nd image you have to be slightly careful while performing above analysis as there are many tiny lines. get back to me for further help